# Why do "new branches" push to previously deleted ones?

Tags: git, github

I have deleted a branch on Github but when I push a new commit to a branch with the same name (assuming it should be new), it still lists activity as if its the previously (deleted) one. How can I fully remove a branch on github so this doesn't occur or force it to create a new branch with the same name?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "it still lists activity as if its the previously deleted one" / what your goal behind deleting the branch is?

Comment: Do note that branches in git are just pointers to commits. There's zero information in a branch other than its names and which commit it points to. If you're trying to change anything about how the revision history looks, you need to concern yourself with the commits, not the branch.

Comment: How exactly did you "delete a branch on GitHub"? And what problem were you _really_ trying to solve? If the idea is make the "same" branch start out from main with just its last commit, throwing away the commits that preceded it after the "split" from main, what you're doing is not how to do that.

Comment: In github you can click branches and the Delete / bin icon. One would assume that branch is fully gone! Clearly not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I push a new commit to a branch with the same name (assuming it
> should be new), it still lists activity as if its the previously
> (deleted) one.

Yes, this is just how branches in Git (and on Github) work.

In Git, **a branch is nothing but a name** (which points to some commit). If you delete a branch in a repository and re-create it, Git has no way of knowing that the branch "feature1" you just re-created is supposed to be different from "feature1" that was deleted yesterday.

There is no way around this. The usual way to resolve this is to *not reuse branch names*. Re-using branch names is (IMHO) problematic anyway, because it can quickly become confusing. So just do not do this :-).

---

Note that there is nothing inherently wrong with having long-running and constantly changing branches if you want to - for example, the development of Git itself uses several long-running branches which change regularly (["next", "seen"...](https://git-scm.com/docs/SubmittingPatches)). However, if one of these branches is deleted and re-created (which can indeed happen), Git itself will not know about it, therefore the Git project explicitly documents when and how these branches may change, so developers are aware.